# How to use value of a class enum : char as a char argument of function?

Tags: c++, enums, casting

In an endeavor to write cleaner code I'm (likely over-)using `enums`, like so:

```
enum class SoundFileCode : char {
  PC_STARTUP = '1', // probably never used
  LOADING_READY = '2',
  VOICE_RECOGNITION_ON = '3',
  VOICE_RECOGNITION_OFF = '4',
  DISPENSING = '5'
};
```

I'd like to be able to pass that value to a function in a nice clean way (preferably without having to cast anything to make it a cleaner API):

`sendRemoteAudioMessage(SoundFileCode::LOADING_READY);`

Here's the function signature:
`void sendRemoteAudioMessage(char audioCode){ }`

I see you shaking your head. You already know the error I'm going to get: `Compilation error: cannot convert 'SoundFileCode' to 'char' for argument '1' to 'void sendRemoteAudioMessage(char)'`

My goals are:

1. To make it easy for code completion to suggest these hard-coded constant values
2. To be able to reuse the same names, but keep them namespaced cleanly within their own enum
3. To make it easy for a programmer to just select a code and pass it to the function without thinking too hard about it.

If enums won't foot the bill here, what's a good approach? Creating a class with some static constants? (this is likely how I'd approach it in PHP / Java)

**UPDATE**

The following (if somewhat verbose) approach compiles and runs fine. Is there a superior approach?

```
class SoundFileCode {
  public : 
    static const char PC_STARTUP = '1';
    static const char LOADING_READY = '2';
    static const char VOICE_RECOGNITION_ON = '3';
    static const char VOICE_RECOGNITION_OFF = '4';
    static const char DISPENSING = '5';
};
```

Comment: Why don't you use an enum in a class?

Comment: Why doesn't `sendRemoteAudioMessage` just take a `SoundFileCode` as its argument instead of a `char`?

Comment: @NathanPierson potentially brilliant - but I still need to be able to send that code as a char (it's for serial communications). So at some point it needs to be converted. Will a cast within the function cut it?

Comment: @TomAuger to access a `enum class` as its underlying type, you must cast it. The longer you can delay making that cast until you absolutely need it (ie, when interacting with an external system, like a comm port), the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enum class` purposefully disallows implicit casts to the underlying type, so you'd either need `static_cast<>`, or - preferably - take the enum in the callee.

If neither of the above works, e.g. because the functions you call are in a library, you can still do the old trick of wrapping the `enum` into a `namespace` (or `class`):

```
namespace SoundFileCode {
    enum type : char {
        PC_STARTUP = '1',
        // ...
    }
}
```

In this case, you'll still have `SoundFileCode::PC_STARTUP` for the name of the enum value, but you can implicitly cast to `char`. An inconvenience is that now you need `SoundFileCode::type` in declarations of the enum (and other places where the type is used):

```
int main() {
    SoundFileCode::type sfc = SoundFileCode::PC_STARTUP;
    sendRemoteAudioMessage(sfc);
    sendRemoteAudioMessage(SoundFileCode::PC_STARTUP);
}
```

Comment: Is `type` in this context just an arbitrary identifier or is it a special reserved word we need to use? And could you demonstrate how SoundFileCode::type must be used - just asking based on your last senence.

Comment: @TomAuger You can use any name there. Also editing answer to add a demo.

Answer (score 1):

> How to use value of a class enum : char as a char argument of function?

An enum class can be converted to an integer using `static_cast`:

```
sendRemoteAudioMessage(static_cast<char>(SoundFileCode::LOADING_READY));
```

---

> (preferably without having to cast anything to make it a cleaner API):

Ideal solution for a cleaner API is to use the matching parameter type:

```
void sendRemoteAudioMessage(SoundFileCode audioCode)
```

Comment: Yes, but OP wrote that the plan is to avoid explicit casts.

Comment: I like this second approach, but does that mean I need to do the `static_cast<char>` within my function in order to get it to work (I'm not opposed, since that implementation would be "hidden")?

Comment: Yes. Use the descriptive strongly-typed constant in your high-level code, and finally translate it to the raw wire format at the edge, hidden inside the function.